# EF ... Unwanted duplicate values of two fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entity for save Product and Product's Related Products ... there is One to Many Relationship ... Everything is right before storing the information But in the database two duplicate fields are stored
RelatedProducID 
ProductID

```
public class RelatedCatalogs : EntityBase
{
    public Guid ProductID { get; set; }
    public Guid RelatedProducID { get; set; }

    public Product RelatedProductCatalog { get; set; }


    public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

Product Class:

```
public class Product{
    public Guid ProductID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RelatedProductID")]
    public virtual List<RelatedCatalogs> RelatedCatalogs { get; set; }
```

.
.
.
}

What needs to be done now to fix this problem?

Comment: note that the foreign key is called "RelatedProducID", without the 't' like in your data annotation.

Comment: RelatedProduct must be a table that stores two Ids, Id of product, and Id of the related product.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I checked it ... in source that's OK ...

Comment: @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani ... salam ashkan ... I did it, but it did not make any difference

Comment: no I meant that the db design was not right, it wasn't related to your problem.

Comment: @ashkan-mobayen-khiabani  what is my problem solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712199/entity-framework-many-to-many-relationship-to-same-entity-type-but-with-differen),  so try:

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    [InverseProperty("Product")]
    public virtual List<RelatedCatalogs> RelatedCatalogs { get; set; }
}

public class RelatedCatalogs : EntityBase
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public Guid ProductID { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RelatedProductCatalog")]
    public Guid RelatedProductID { get; set; }
    public Product RelatedProductCatalog { get; set; }

    public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can add the mentioned fluent code to avoid cycles:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RelatedCatalogs>()
    .HasRequired(r => r.RelatedProductCatalog)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(r => r.RelatedProductID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<RelatedCatalogs>()
    .HasRequired(r => r.Product)
    .WithMany(p => p.RelatedCatalogs)
    .HasForeignKey(r => r.ProductID);
```